Does proficiency with an ability check that uses a tool but not with the tool itself give any advantages for D&D 5.24?
So, in the new rules (5.24) it says the following description under any tool/kit:

If you have proficiency with a tool, add your Proficiency Bonus to any ability check you make that uses the tool. If you have proficiency in a skill that’s used with that check, you have Advantage on the check too.

What happens if I am proficient with the skill but not the tool? Do I get to add the proficiency to the ability check? Or have an advantage with it?
Also most tools don't specify exactly which skill goes with the ability check, like for example:

Forgery Kit
Ability: Dexterity
Utilize: Mimic 10 or fewer words of someone else’s handwriting (DC
15), or duplicate a wax seal (DC 20)

I'd imagine this is Dex (Sleight of Hand) ability check. Or is this left open on purpose so that the DM decides? But if so, then why suggest Dex?

Heh, I would have guessed a Dex-based Deception check. :)

You add your proficiency bonus.
The rules for proficiency state:

This bonus is applied to a D20 Test when the creature has proficiency in a skill, in a saving throw, or with an item that the creature uses to make the D20 Test.

So if you have proficiency in the skill, and not the tool, you would add your proficiency bonus, and would not have advantage, since you only have advantage when you have proficiency in both.
That said, an ability check with a tool does not have to use a skill. A skill is only used as part of the check if the DM determines that both the tool and the skill may be applied.

@PedroFontanarrosa Correct, and if the DM determines it is appropriate to add a skill you’re proficient with on top of the tool you’re proficient with, you would add you prof bonus and have advantage.

I see, so if I’m understanding correctly:


When using the Forgery Kit, I would generally make a Dexterity ability check. If I’m proficient with the tool, I can add my proficiency bonus to this check.


If the DM instead asks for a specific skill check (like Sleight of Hand) and I’m proficient in that skill, I would have advantage on the check—but only if I’m also proficient with the tool.


If the DM asks for a specific skill check that I’m proficient in, but I’m not proficient with the tool, I would still add my proficiency bonus to the check, but I wouldn’t have advantage.



@PedroFontanarrosa Yeah, I think that covers it.

To answer your second question, the only description of skills is a summary list found on page 14 of the PHB with entries that reads

Skill, Ability, Example Use


Investigation, Intelligence, Find obscure
information in books, or deduce how something works.

However, you will find more concrete examples scattered throughout the entries of the book like this description of a lock on page 226.

LOCK (10 GP) A Lock comes with a key. Without the key, a creature can
use Thieves' Tools to pick this Lock with a successful DC 15 Dexterity
(Sleight of Hand) check.

That will give you information about what skill corresponds to the use of a tool.
As a note that the PHB 2024 compared to the PHB 2014 doesn't have a full description of each skill and what they can do. As of September, 2024 I suspect the full answer to your question will have to wait until the release of the DMG 2024. Especially given how different the organization of the 2024 PHB is to the 2014 PHB.
